# robot_pose_ekf frequency too slow?

Tags: navigation, odometry, husky, frequency, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I am currently trying to modify the Husky robot by adding an IMU to it and use the robot_pose_ekf to get a pose of the robot by combining the input of the wheel odometry and the IMU. I do hope, that this is not a copy of this (answers.ros.org/question/12562/is-robot_pose_ekf-acting-correctly/, not enough karma for links), as I do not get any warnings (frame_id of the IMU is set to base_footprint).

Things are working fine so far, although the update rate of the robot_pose_ekf is very slow, even if all relevant frequencies are set to 30 Hz or more. Currently robot_pose_ekf publishes only with a rate of 0.2 Hz, although it should report with a rate of 30 Hz. For example `rosservice call /robot1/robot_pose_ekf/get_status` will yield the following:

```
status: Input:
 * Odometry sensor
   - is active
   - received 1227 messages
   - listens to topic /robot1/odom
 * IMU sensor
   - is NOT active
   - received 1343 messages
   - listens to topic /robot1/imu_data
 * Visual Odometry sensor
   - is NOT active
   - received 0 messages
   - listens to topic 
Output:
 * Robot pose ekf filter
   - is active
   - sent 47 messages
   - pulishes on topics /robot1/robot_pose_ekf/robot1_tf/odom and /tf
```

The code I am using to include the robot_pose_ekf is the following:

```
<node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf">       
    <param name="freq" value="30.0" />
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0" />     
    <param name="odom_used" value="true" />
    <param name="imu_used" value="true" />
    <param name="vo_used" value="false" />
    <param name="output_frame" value="odom" />      
</node>
```

I would be delighted, if any of you could shed any light on my problem and help me to get a decent publishing frequency for the robot_pose_ekf topic. Thanks in advance for any answers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142326/robot_pose_ekf-frequency-too-slow?/) by [Florian Blatt](https://answers.ros.org/users/11326/florian-blatt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-20**:
Without looking at this closely, the "is NOT active" line in "IMU sensor" strikes me as odd.

**Comment by [Florian Blatt](https://answers.ros.org/users/11326/florian-blatt/) on 2014-03-20**:
Thanks for the answer, any idea on how to activate the IMU sensor? "rostopic info /robot1/imu_data" shows, that the ekf subscribes to the imu topic.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-21**:
Unfortunately not. You might want to dig in the code to find out why IMU is shown as not active. Also what frequency is your odom input?

**Comment by [Florian Blatt](https://answers.ros.org/users/11326/florian-blatt/) on 2014-03-21**:
If I haven't made an error looking into the Husky model, the odom frequency should be set to 100. As far as I could discern from the robot_pose_ekf package, the pose will only update if it gets two different inputs with a later timestamp, but IMHO this should not matter in this case.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-21**:
you can easily check with `rostopic hz /robot1/odom`

**Comment by [Florian Blatt](https://answers.ros.org/users/11326/florian-blatt/) on 2014-03-22**:
"rostopic hz..." tells me, that odom has a rate around 800, should be fast enough Tod allow the robot_pose_ekf to update with a rate of 30 Hz. Maybe I just have Tod take a peek at the ekf source code, but thanks either way.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-22**:
Also, maybe add a `output="screen"` to your launch file, to see if there is any output of the ekf node that you might be missing.

**Comment by [Florian Blatt](https://answers.ros.org/users/11326/florian-blatt/) on 2014-03-22**:
Thanks for the hint, I did not know about that parameter yet. I will try it out and check whether ekf  has anything more to say ;)

**Comment by [Florian Blatt](https://answers.ros.org/users/11326/florian-blatt/) on 2014-03-23**:
Thanks again for the hint, it seems, that I do have a similar problem converting the IMU message to robot1_tf/base_footprint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Further investigation revealed, that this seems to be a problem of a missing tf transformation. Currently I need to include the tf_prefix parameter in the frame_id of the IMU to get this to work correctly.

EDIT: I just had to remove the tf_prefix and everything works fine... Thanks again for the help and the answers.

---

Originally posted by [Florian Blatt](https://answers.ros.org/users/11326/florian-blatt/) with karma: 16 on 2014-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moejoegoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/14051/moejoegoe/) on 2014-04-10**:
Hello Florian,
it seems I have the same problem as you had! Can you please explain in more detail how you solved it!?
Bye Matthias

**Comment by [Florian Blatt](https://answers.ros.org/users/11326/florian-blatt/) on 2014-04-10**:
Hi Matthias, as I stated above, I used the tf_prefix parameter, so that I would have different name spaces for multiple robots. Removing this parameter did the trick. Otherwise maybe you need to post a little bit more information about your setup ;)